# Android: EditText dont work

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

this code is not working, i started android development 1 hour ago :)

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
final EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Editable ec = edt.getText();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"HELLO !"+ec,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

How can i fix this ?

Thank you.

Comment: And what is the error message ? what you mean by not working?

Comment: As constructive criticism, this answer could have easily been answered for you already by searching StackOverflow/ other coding sites. Also, you didn't explain what the issue was, just that "it isn't working".

Answer (score 2):

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"HELLO !"+edt.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
String txt = ed1.getText().tostring();
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"HELLO!"+txt,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```